# Selling units/shares in my startup to my Roth IRA

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, limited-liability-company, start-up

Since I can't transfer/gift shares directly to my Roth IRA, what's the most tax-efficient way for my Roth IRA to take ownership of as many units of my startup as possible?

Is this even possible? If not why?

Comment: Upvoting: It's a bad idea, but a good question.

Comment: The question assumes that it is possible to hold shares of my own LLC company within a Roth IRA. I think this is an important question but needs to be refrased in order to be answered correctly.

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: @IanEdington The reason for downvotes might be that some people have read littleadv's response which is right on point, and possibly read OP rkr's self-answer which suggests directing the IRA custodian of a non-self-directed IRA to make blatantly illegal transactions.

Comment: Thank you @DilipSarwate for your answer. It makes sense that people would downvote for those reasons. However, do those same reasons not make this an extremely important question to be asked and answered properly? I have been asked this exact same question in Canada about RRSP's and TFSA (like 401k and Roth IRA). If the answer to a question is 'No that's illegal' it doesn't make the question any less important.

Comment: @IanEdington There is a specific prohibition (as stated in the IRS's Publication 590) disallowing the owner, beneficiary, family member, or fiduciary (custodian) from purchasing property belonging to the owner and bringing it into the IRA. While littleadv's answer does not provide this level of detail, he nonetheless stated quite clearly that bringing one's own property into an IRA is prohibited. _After_ reading this answer, the OP _still_ wants to know if he can circumvent this proscription by demanding that the IRA custodian purchase shares in his LLC instead of doing it himself (continued)

Comment: ... in a self-directed IRA. In other words, he wants this group's blessing on an illegal activity and will continue to come up with more scenarios to get his LLC into his IRA. The down-votes are fully deserved: **the question has been asked and has been answered (and answered correctly)** but the OP does not want to accept what he has been told. As such, the OP's question is not a useful addition to this forum _beyond_ what has already been said.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - Your judgment is incorrect, I do not have >=50% control or ownership of my LLC, therefore it is not a prohibited transaction if my LLC were to issue units and sell those to my IRA although I've been advised that the IRS may contest this since the definition of "control" is a grey area. This is a unconventional practice but not entirely without precedence (Mitt Romney's SEP-IRA is invested in Bain's GP entity, Peter Thiel directed his IRA custodian to buy shares of PayPal while he was co-founder and CEO).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I want to follow up that I understand the risk of crossing the line on the IRS's policy on prohibited transactions.

I've found that the best approach is simply to issue units of my startup, XYZ LP at some fair market value determined by my accounting firm, and have my IRA custodian purchase those units. Since the profit potential of a startup is extremely volatile and speculative, the units can be valued at a reasonably low unit price.

Comment: If you succeed in accomplishing this transaction I would be very interested in knowing how you actually do it and the circumstances of the transaction.

Answer (score 9):

> Since I can't transfer/gift shares directly to my Roth IRA, what's the
>   most tax-efficient way for my Roth IRA to take ownership of as many
>   units of XYZ LP as possible?

None.

> XYZ LP has some high fair market value so selling those shares
>   directly to my Roth IRA seems incorrect.

Also - illegal.

> I thought of incorporating an LLC ("MY-OWN LLC"), investing my Roth
>   IRA in MY-OWN LLC, then gifting my partnership units to MY-OWN LLC,
>   but the $300~ per-year costs of running an LLC is relatively hefty and
>   I think I can only gift $13,000 in partnership units before getting
>   taxed.

No, you cannot do that either.

---

That ^ there - that's the bottom line. Bottom line is that you **cannot** self-deal in a self-directed IRA (or any other retirement account). That is what is called a **[prohibited transaction](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-Prohibited-Transactions)**. Any of the types of the transactions above will lead to your self directed IRA being disqualified, *in its entirety*, and the whole worth of that IRA will be considered distribution to you, taxed, and penalized.

You cannot transfer anything to your IRA that you own other than *cash* (or cash equivalent, i.e.: you can deposit a check, wire money from a bank account, etc). You cannot transfer any property, in any way, into your IRA.

Comment: +1 I think that last paragraph should be in boldface to emphasize that point to the OP; else he will be coming back with more ideas to accomplish what he wants to do.